# Sketch - How to "update" multiple text styles at once?

Tags: sketch-app

I am managing a design system and I have multiple text styles that I would like to change at once (let's say I need to change their color and make them all red), how can I "update" all of them in one go?

I would like to make sure I can change the text styles consistently without having to select them one by one and then "update" the base style from the property panel for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage text styles with Sketch
All you have to do is create a text line or click on an existing one, and ine the right panel : **Appearance > create text style**

[image: Create text style]

Once you have created your style, if you update a text that has this style applied, Sketch offers in the same menu the option to update all the others :

[image: Update text style]